# Spark Imputer for filling up missing values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, imputation

requirement -

In the Picture attached, consider the first 3 columns as my raw data. Some rows have quantity column as NULL value which is exactly what I want to fill up.
In an Ideal case, I would fill up any NULL value with the previous KNOWN value.

Spark Imputer seemed to be a very easily implementable library that can help me fill missing values.
But here the issue is,Spark Imputer is limited to mean or Median calculation according to all NON-BULL values present in the data frame as a result of which I don't get desired result (4th column in the Pic).

Logic -

```
val imputer = new Imputer()
          .setInputCols(Array("quantity"))
          .setOutputCols(Array("quantity_imputed"))
          .setStrategy("mean")

val model = imputer.fit(new_combinedDf)
model.transform(new_combinedDf).show()
```

Result -

[image: Result]

Now is it possible  to limit the Mean calculation for EACH null value to be the MEAN of last n values ?
i.e
For 2020-09-26 , where we get the first null value, Is it possible to tweak Spark Imputer to calculate the Mean over last n values only instead of all non-null values in the dataframe ?

Comment: you can accomplish that with custom window specs using functions `rowsBetween` and `rangeBetween`.

Comment: @Jay, Thanks for replying. But I was wondering how can we use Window Functions with Spark Imputer ? It would be of great help if you could elaborate further.

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/deep-dive-into-apache-spark-window-functions-7b4e39ad3c86) article goes into detail.